# Android apps targeted at Android 2.2 and Google Maps V1

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.2-froyo

I'm pretty new to Android dev, not so new to Java. Anyhow I'm in the planning stage of my application which will rely heavily on Google map api.

I wanted to jump in to the code today but came across this dilemma. I won't be using any special UI components or anything so new that I would need to set my targeted version to higher than 2.2.

First thing I would like to display a map via Google map api. Anyhow the problem I have is when visiting https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/ To learn more about the API and how to use it I found out that it's no longer supported and has been replaced with V2. What bugged me was the statement that they are no longer releasing api keys for Google maps V1. And the V2 requires minimal Android API to be 17 which puts my app targeted at phones running Android 4.3+ which does not really cover that much devices.

Does this mean my application is a no-go and I have to deal with it being targeted for Android 4.3+ or can I still use V1 and target my app for Android 2.2+

Thanks in advance

Comment: just as a tip going off of what keyboardsurfer said you always want to target the highest SDK possible. You can set a minimum sdk meaning all phones > your minimum will work. Just because you wont use any "special UI components" does not mean you should not target the highest SDK since there are always bug fixes and improvements. Users now a days are use to the holo look and if they have a device that uses the holo theme they expect it to have that look and not have it look like crappy 2.2 android

Comment: @tyczj But if I set minimal 2.2 I cant use Holo theme. Is my best option then build for 4.3+ and then port what can be ported to 2.2 and essentially making 2 apps ? What should my compile option be if I go one app only min 2.2 target 4.3 compile with 4.3 as well ?

Comment: for devices < 3.0 you are correct they dont have the holo theme but that does not mean you should just target 2.2. The UI in android is (for the lack of a better word) dynamic meaning the images are different over different versions of SDK's so when you target the highest SDK your app will use the updated UI images for that SDK. Just do what `keyboardsurfer` said to and set a minSdkVersion of 8 (2.2) and targetSdkVersion of 18 (4.3) and you will be fine, there is no need to make 2 apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minSdkVersion` of apps using the Google Maps V2 API for Android is not 17, but 8.
What you mean is probably the `targetSdkVersion` which should always be the highest available.
So you're good to go there.